# Live Streaming Video

Tags: flash, video, video-streaming, live-streaming

I want to do a live stream. I am using Flash as the client and FMIS as the server technology. I wanted to know if there is any way to do live video encoding via a web interface?

As-In, now I use Flash Media Live Encoder to encode the video stream and publish, I wanted to know means in which I can use a web based encoder (similar to Flash Media Live Encoder, but with a web interface) that could publish the encoded stream to my server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **flash player itself** has encoding capabilities. Results are not as good as FME, but it worlks for third parties not wanting to install additional software.